# CMakeLists include Header File from subdirectories

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to work with CMake for the first time and am struggling to link header files into my main. My cmake directory looks like this:

```
Project
| CmakeLists.txt
| src
|| CMakeLists.txt
|| Main.cpp
| Libs
|| CMakeLists.txt
|| headers 
|||obstacle_detection.hpp
||source
|||obstacle_detection.cpp
|build
||"build files"
```

I would like to link the files in the `headers` folder to main, but what I currently have does not appear to work. The following runs the CMake command correctly but fails to compile with the `make` command, being unable to find the given header file. My CMakeLists files are as follows:

Project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Sensivision)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}") 
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(realsense2 REQUIRED)
find_library(darknet REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(libs)
add_subdirectory(src)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} obstacle_detection)
```

Libs:

```
add_library(
    obstacle_detection
    headers/obstacle_detection.hpp
    sources/obstacle_detection.cpp
)


target_link_directories(obstacle_detection PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

src:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${realsense2_LIBRARY})
```

My include in main.cpp is

```
include <obstacle_detection.hpp>
```

I have also tried

```
include <headers/obstacle_detection.hpp>
```

and

```
include <obstacle_detection>
```

Each gives the error:

```
obstacle_detection.hpp: no such file or directory
```

What am I doing incorrectly to link the header to the main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added any include directories to the `obstacle_detection` library. By listing the header file in the `add_library` call, this may allow the header to be displayed in an IDE, but it doesn't do anything for compilation. You should use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/target_include_directories.html) to add the `headers` directory as an *include directory* for the `obstacle_detection` library. Otherwise, it, and other consuming targets, will have **no knowledge** of the headers in that directory.

```
add_library(
    obstacle_detection
    headers/obstacle_detection.hpp
    sources/obstacle_detection.cpp
)

# Add this line. 
target_include_directories(obstacle_detection PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers)

# Not sure this line is necessary, as it doesn't appear you actually link anything...
target_link_directories(obstacle_detection PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

You haven't shown the CMake code in the `src` directory, but be sure to **link** the `obstacle_detection` library target to the main target, e.g.:

```
target_link_libraries(MyExeTarget PRIVATE obstacle_detection)
```

In addition, because this header file is *local*, it is best if you use quotes to include the header:

```
#include "obstacle_detection.hpp"
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue. What is the difference between include and link in this context?

Comment: @noble_gasses Header files are usually not *linked*; rather, they are used during the compilation process to provide definitions for your classes/variable/etc. You specify this with CMake using `target_include_directories`. After compilation, the resulting object files (and potentially other existing libraries) get **linked** to create a new library or executable during the link stage. You can specify other libraries to link with CMake using `target_link_libraries`. See the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6264249/3987854) for some overview of the different stages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to add folder where your headers are located and `#include <header.hpp>` where needed.
Ex:

```
libs cmake:
add_library(
    obstacle_detection
    headers/obstacle_detection.hpp
    sources/obstacle_detection.cpp
)
target_include_directories(obstacle_detection PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

cpp:
#include <headers/obstacle_detection.hpp>
```